# Getting connection refused when trying to connect to mail server using imaplib

Tags: python, email, smtp, imaplib

I'm on a work network. I want to be able to download the attachment from coming from a specific email address to my local directory. But, for that first I need to be able to connect to the mail server. I'm doing the following to connect:

```
self.connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(mail_server)
self.connection.login(username, password)
self.connection.select(readonly=False)
```

However the above gives me "Connection Refused error". However, when I do this:

```
mail_server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.something.com')
print(mail_server)
```

It makes the connection. Is there a way I could use `SMTP` instead of `imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(mail_server)` to be able to download attachments from email? Or some other work around?

Comment: You should specify a port number alongside the mail_server (993 i guess), try that way, should be enough, otherwise it might be a proxy/firewall problem
`self.connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(mail_server, 993)`

Comment: @MrRobot No, 993 does not work. I mentioned that I'm on a work network, so yes there is firewall, but smtp works, so I wanted to know if there was a workaround to this (imaplib) as well.

Comment: Did you try poplib ? I honestly don't know of a way to workaround this with smtp...

Comment: SMTP can only send mail, not receive it.